# Rate Limiting HTTP Requests (via http.HandlerFunc middleware)

Tags: http, go

I'm looking to write a small piece of rate-limiting middleware that:

1. Allows me to set a sensible rate (say, 10 req/s) per remote IP
2. Possibly (but it doesn't have to) allow for bursts
3. Drops (closes?) connections that exceed the rate and returns a HTTP 429

I can then wrap this around authentication routes or other routes that might be vulnerable to brute-force attacks (i.e. password reset URLs using a token that expires, etc.). The chances of someone brute forcing a 16 or 24 byte token are really low, but it doesn't hurt to go that extra step.

I've had a look at https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/RateLimiting but am not sure how to reconcile it with http.Request(s). Further, I'm not sure how we'd "track" requests from a given IP over any period of time.

Ideally I'd end up with something like this, noting that I'm behind a reverse proxy (nginx) so we're checking for the `REMOTE_ADDR` HTTP header rather than using `r.RemoteAddr`:

```
// Rate-limiting middleware
func rateLimit(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        remoteIP := r.Header.Get("REMOTE_ADDR")
        for req := range (what here?) {
            // what here?
            // w.WriteHeader(429) and close the request if it exceeds the limit
            // else pass to the next handler in the chain
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
}

// Example routes
r.HandleFunc("/login", use(loginForm, rateLimit, csrf)
r.HandleFunc("/form", use(editHandler, rateLimit, csrf)

// Middleware wrapper, for context
func use(h http.HandlerFunc, middleware ...func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    for _, m := range middleware {
        h = m(h)
    }

    return h
}
```

I'd appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rate limiting example you've linked to is a general one. It uses range because it gets requests over a channel.

It's a different story with HTTP requests, but there's nothing really complicated here. Note that you don't iterate over a channel of requests, or anything -- your HandlerFunc is called for every incoming request *separately*.

```
func rateLimit(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        remoteIP := r.Header.Get("REMOTE_ADDR")
        if exceededTheLimit(remoteIP) {
            w.WriteHeader(429)
            // it then returns, not passing the request down the chain
        } else {
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r);
        }
    }       
}
```

Now, choosing the place to store the rate limit counters is up to you. One solution would be to simply use a global map (don't forget safe concurrent access) that would map IPs to their request counters. However, you would have to be aware of how long ago the requests were made.

Sergio suggested using Redis. Its key-value nature is a perfect fit for simple structures like this and you get expiration for free.

Comment: Thanks Justinas. Thinking through the design: a key that is some combination of path + remote address with a simple counter should do the trick, with a (configurable) expiry? i.e. `"SETEX", path + remoteIP, reqLimit, counter"` where counter is an int retrieved on each request, checked/incremented, and sent back to Redis? The catch here is that we need to make sure we don't "reset" the counter until it expires.

Comment: I'd say you should do `SETEX path+remoteIP expirationPeriod counter`, then INCR on every request. The thing is, INCR won't reset the expiration time.

Comment: Ah, good call. Looking at the Redis docs they actually cover [a (simplified) implementation of this](http://redis.io/commands/incr) by having the key be `path+IP+time.Now().Second()`. Downsides to this, if any? Seems a sensible way to approach. Also cautious about any race conditions here, although this may be taken care of by Redis itself (?).

Comment: I'd still go with `path+IP` as the key, counter as the value, with expiration set and `INCR`-ing on every request. `INCR` is an atomic operation, there should be no race conditions.

Comment: I've [whipped up a quick example](https://gist.github.com/elithrar/14cd2721457ae00032a4): from what I can determine (at the end of a long week!) we should: `INCR path+IP` (which will set our key to 1 if it doesn't exist), check if the return value > limit (return 429 + skip the rest of our handlers) else if current == 1 `SETEX path+IP, 1 second, 1)` (set an expiry on "fresh" keys) else pass to the next handler in the chain. Is this right? (I'll let you go after this!) ;)

Comment: The example isn't completely runnable, but that should work. Besides, since you already set value early in the function, you don't need `SETEX`. `EXPIRE` is a simpler alternative that only sets the key expiration (and not the value) http://redis.io/commands/expire . SETEX might even lead to a race condition: Req 1: `INCR` (val: 1), Req 2: `INCR` (val: 2), Req 1: `SETEX` (val: 1), Req 2: `SETEX` (val: 1).

Comment: Perfect, thanks again for your help. I should be able to hack this together (and include some tests) and release it for public consumption as well, since it's a popular use case.

Answer (score 4):

You could store the data in redis. Here's a very useful command that even mentions rate limiting application in its documentation: [INCR](http://redis.io/commands/incr). Redis will also handle cleanup of old data (via expiration of old keys).

Also, with redis being the rate limiter storage, you can use multiple frontend processes that share this central storage.

Some would argue that going to external process each time is expensive. But password reset page is not a kind of page that absolutely demands best performance. Also, if you place the redis on the same machine, latency should be pretty low.

Comment: I'm already running Redis for server-side sessions (via redistore, so at a higher level) but don't mind leaning on it as utmost performance here isn't a problem. Some [Flask middleware](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/70/) leverages Redis for the same goal. I'm not sure how to start on the http.Request logic though: I can probably figure out how to use Redigo once I get that bedded down.

Answer (score 4):

I have done something simple and similar this morning, I think it could help your case.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html/"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    log.Println("Listening..")
    go clearLastRequestsIPs()
    go clearBlockedIPs()
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", middleware(nil))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

// Stores last requests IPs
var lastRequestsIPs []string

// Block IP for 6 hours
var blockedIPs []string

func middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ipAddr := strings.Split(r.RemoteAddr, ":")[0]
        if existsBlockedIP(ipAddr) {
            http.Error(w, "", http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        // how many requests the current IP made in last 5 mins
        requestCounter := 0
        for _, ip := range lastRequestsIPs {
            if ip == ipAddr {
                requestCounter++
            }
        }
        if requestCounter >= 1000 {
            blockedIPs = append(blockedIPs, ipAddr)
            http.Error(w, "", http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        lastRequestsIPs = append(lastRequestsIPs, ipAddr)

        // Don't cut the chain of middlewares
        if next == nil {
            http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func existsBlockedIP(ipAddr string) bool {
    for _, ip := range blockedIPs {
        if ip == ipAddr {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func existsLastRequest(ipAddr string) bool {
    for _, ip := range lastRequestsIPs {
        if ip == ipAddr {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Clears lastRequestsIPs array every 5 mins
func clearLastRequestsIPs() {
    for {
        lastRequestsIPs = []string{}
        time.Sleep(time.Minute * 5)
    }
}

// Clears blockedIPs array every 6 hours
func clearBlockedIPs() {
    for {
        blockedIPs = []string{}
        time.Sleep(time.Hour * 6)
    }
}
```

It's still not precise yet, however, it would help as a simple example of rate limiter. you can improve it by adding requested path, http method and even authentication as factors to decide whether the flow is an attack or not.

Comment: You need to protect (synchronize) writes/reads from your global slices.

Comment: I simplified your example with a map: https://play.golang.org/p/hmEguNLOMO

Answer (score 2):

Here's my rate limit middleware implementation. It works very nicely as a global rate limiter, or a rate limiter for an individual request. I use it extensively in my apps.

Here is what you get with it:

- no external dependencies
- testable
- configurable
- adds headers so a client can understand how many requests that have left before they are limited, etc.
- automatically removes expired data.

First, the implementation:

```
r := router.New()
stats := stats.New()
r.With(middleware.RateLimit(1, time.Minute * 1, stats)).Post("/contact", c.Contact)
```

The middleware about will allow one request pet minute when making a `POST` request to `/contact`.

Here is the middleware:

```
package middleware

import (
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

// Stats is an interface to an underlying hash table/map data
// structure. Implement it however you'd like.
type Stats interface {
    // Reset will reset the map.
    Reset()

    // Add would add "count" to the map at the key of "identifier",
    // and returns an int which is the total count of the value 
    // at that key.
    Add(identifier string, count int) int
}

// RateLimit middleware is a generic rate limiter that can be used in any scenario
// because it allows granular rate limiting for each specific request. Or you can
// set the rate limiter on the entire router group. It's just a HandlerFunc.
func RateLimit(limit int, window time.Duration, stats Stats) func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    var windowStart time.Time

    // Clear the rate limit stats after each window.
    ticker := time.NewTicker(window)
    go func() {
        windowStart = time.Now()

        for range ticker.C {
            windowStart = time.Now()
            stats.Reset()
        }
    }()

    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        h := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            value := int(stats.Add(identifyRequest(r), 1))

            XRateLimitRemaining := limit - value
            if XRateLimitRemaining < 0 {
                XRateLimitRemaining = 0
            }

            w.Header().Add("X-Rate-Limit-Limit", strconv.Itoa(limit))
            w.Header().Add("X-Rate-Limit-Remaining", strconv.Itoa(XRateLimitRemaining))
            w.Header().Add("X-Rate-Limit-Reset", strconv.Itoa(int(window.Seconds()-time.Since(windowStart).Seconds())+1))

            if value >= limit {
                w.WriteHeader(429)
                // Do something else...
            } else {
                next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            }
        }

        return http.HandlerFunc(h)
    }
}

// identifyRequest gets an identifier from the request context.
func identifyRequest(r *http.Request) string {
    // Identify your request here (get IP address, etc.)
}
```